# Spring Boot - Class-Path manifest attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classpath

i'm new to spring boot and setting up a project currently. When i run the 
application it runs fine, but in the console i'm getting this not sure. can you guys help me out. Thanks

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/txw2-2.3.1.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/stax-ex-1.8.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar,file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a problem with the spring-boot-devtools. I had the same issue in my project and it was gone after I removed the spring-boot-devtools dependency from the Gradle build.

Comment: It was the right answer for me, but I don't understand why...maybe a problem with the SpringBoot version? I would like someone could answer us

Answer (score 2):

If you comment out the line `developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")` in `build.gradle` the output stated above does not occur.

From: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11322

Tks to @niravassar